# Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0. Searched in the following locations:

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am trying to add firebase to my project, I am following the steps from firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0
help please! I am getting this error when I try to sync gradle.

Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0.
Searched in the following locations: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.1.0/google-services-4.1.0.pom
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.1.0/google-services-4.1.0.jar

why is that happening, I visited this link https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/ to be sure the repository has that .pom, or .jar, but I see this [image]

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    google()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

---

```
....
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation project(":mupdf")
implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.+@aar'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
implementation 'com.weigan:loopView:0.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
// Add the In-App Messaging depencency:
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.0.5'
```

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Please also add the content for the other build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
buildscript {
repositories {
mavenCentral()
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
google()

}
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

...

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: Is v4.2.0 official? It does not appear in the official documentation. Moreover, I am getting the same error when trying to use that version (Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0)

Comment: For me the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to add google repository like: 
`maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }`

instead of google()